# traverse linked list of child nodes across multiple ancestors based on values in XPath

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

One of our vendors stores their information in XML code almost linked list style. I've been having difficulty coming up with a way to traverse and connect all the data. The following is the XML code:

```
<bibliographic-data>
  <reference>
     <document-id>
       <doc-number>15492293</doc-number>
     </document-id>
  </reference>
</bibliographic-data>


    <related-documents>
            <divider>
                <relation>
                    <parent-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>09861196</doc-number>
                            <date>20010518</date>
                        </document-id>
                        <parent-document>
                            <document-id>
                                <code>UC</code>
                                <doc-number>6514193</doc-number>
                                <date>20030204</date>
                            </document-id>
                        </parent-document>
                    </parent-doc>
                    <child-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>10665793</doc-number>
                        </document-id>
                    </child-doc>
                </relation>
            </divider>      
            <paperback>
                <relation>
                    <parent-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>14711658</doc-number>
                            <date>20150513</date>
                        </document-id>
                        <parent-status>SHELVED</parent-status>
                    </parent-doc>
                    <child-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>15492293</doc-number>
                        </document-id>
                    </child-doc>
                </relation>
            </paperback>
            <paperback>
                <relation>
                    <parent-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>14473159</doc-number>
                            <date>20140829</date>
                        </document-id>
                        <parent-document>
                            <document-id>
                                <code>UC</code>
                                <doc-number>9636401</doc-number>
                                <date>20170502</date>
                            </document-id>
                        </parent-document>
                    </parent-doc>
                    <child-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>14711658</doc-number>
                        </document-id>
                    </child-doc>
                </relation>
            </paperback>

            <paperback>
                <relation>
                    <parent-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>12823700</doc-number>
                            <date>20100625</date>
                        </document-id>
                        <parent-document>
                            <document-id>
                                <code>UC</code>
                                <doc-number>8470294</doc-number>
                                <date>20130625</date>
                            </document-id>
                        </parent-document>
                    </parent-doc>
                    <child-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>13911616</doc-number>
                        </document-id>
                    </child-doc>
                </relation>
            </paperback>
            <paperback>
                <relation>
                    <parent-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>10665793</doc-number>
                            <date>20030919</date>
                        </document-id>
                        <parent-document>
                            <document-id>
                                <code>UC</code>
                                <doc-number>7776310</doc-number>
                                <date>20100817</date>
                            </document-id>
                        </parent-document>
                    </parent-doc>
                    <child-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>12823700</doc-number>
                        </document-id>
                    </child-doc>
                </relation>
            </paperback>
            <hardcover>
                <relation>
                    <parent-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>13911616</doc-number>
                            <date>20130613</date>
                        </document-id>
                        <parent-document>
                            <document-id>
                                <code>UC</code>
                                <doc-number>8821835</doc-number>
                                <date>20140902</date>
                            </document-id>
                        </parent-document>
                    </parent-doc>
                    <child-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>14473159</doc-number>
                        </document-id>
                    </child-doc>
                </relation>
            </hardcover>
            <hardcover>
                <relation>
                    <parent-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>09861326</doc-number>
                            <date>20010518</date>
                        </document-id>
                        <parent-document>
                            <document-id>
                                <code>UC</code>
                                <doc-number>6746661</doc-number>
                                <date>20040608</date>
                            </document-id>
                        </parent-document>
                    </parent-doc>
                    <child-doc>
                        <document-id>
                            <code>UC</code>
                            <doc-number>09861196</doc-number>
                        </document-id>
                    </child-doc>
                </relation>
            </hardcover>
        </related-documents>
```

I am trying to traverse all the nodes using the child and parent doc-number fields. it should connect 15492293 should start chain followed by 14711658 -> 14473159 -> 13911616 -> 12823700 -> 10665793 -> 09861196 -> 09861326.

I have attempted to use the following XPAth expression:
for $i in (./divider, ./paperback, ./hardcover)
[relation/child-doc/document-id/doc-number = /bibliographic-data/reference/document-id/doc-number]
return
for $f in $i
return 
$f[relation/child-doc/document-id/doc-number = $i/relation/parent-doc/document-id/doc-number]

What is an elegant way to traverse through nodes with multiple ancestors almost linked list style. Any assistance will be helpful. I can provide further explanation upon request.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the structure of the XML and the description of the task together with the XPath snippet. Do you have two document with data or where does the path `/bibliographic-data/reference/document-id/doc-number` try to select from? I don't see any `/bibliographic-data/reference/document-id/doc-number` such elements in your XML sample. In what way is `parent-doc` different from `parent-document` in that sample. As for the example chain of numbers, is the use of `15492293` just an example number you want to start with or is that somehow the root (or the leaf) of the tree?

Comment: 15492293 == /bibliographic-data/reference/document-id/doc-number in the example. Sorry I failed to mention that fact until now. The document we receive from the vendor is so voluminous; I did not want to distract from the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write a recursive function following the reference which is best done with the use of a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="start-id">15492293</xsl:param>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:key name="parent" match="related-documents/*" use="relation/child-doc/document-id/doc-number"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:get-ancestor-ids" as="xs:integer*">
        <xsl:param name="item" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:sequence 
            select="let $parent-id := $item/relation/parent-doc/document-id/doc-number,
                        $parent := key('parent', $parent-id, root($item)) 
                        return (xs:integer($parent-id), $parent!mf:get-ancestor-ids(.))"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:value-of select="$start-id, mf:get-ancestor-ids(key('parent', $start-id))" separator=" -> "/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaF1 gives the result

```
15492293 -> 14711658 -> 14473159 -> 13911616 -> 12823700 -> 10665793 -> 9861196 -> 9861326
```

The example uses some XSLT and XPath 3 features like `let` or `!` but you can of course rewrite that for XSLT and XPath 2.0 using `xsl:variable` instead of the `let` and `$parent/mf:get-ancestor-ids(.)` or `if ($parent) then mf:get-ancestor-ids($parent) else ()` for the `$parent!mf:get-ancestor-ids(.)`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="start-id">15492293</xsl:param>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:key name="parent" match="related-documents/*" use="relation/child-doc/document-id/doc-number"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:get-ancestor-ids" as="xs:integer*">
        <xsl:param name="item" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="parent-id"
          select="$item/relation/parent-doc/document-id/doc-number"/>
        <xsl:variable name="parent"
          select="key('parent', $parent-id, root($item))"/>
        <xsl:sequence 
            select="xs:integer($parent-id), $parent/mf:get-ancestor-ids(.)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="$start-id, mf:get-ancestor-ids(key('parent', $start-id))" separator=" -> "/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/93nvfd2

Comment: I really appreciate your time and effort. I have not verified the solution but confident it might work. Is there anyway this could be done with just an XPATH 2.0 expression? If not would it be asking too much to translate this into XSLT 2.0 and XPATH 2.0? I do not quite understand what is going on and how it all works.

Comment: @Hobbyist, I have added an XSLT 2 version of the original XSLT 3 suggestion. As for giving a pure XPath 2 expression without first declaring a recursive function, I am not sure that is possible given that we need to follow the unknown number of levels of references.